# Using COUNT in triggers before insert into table

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert, count

I am new to MySQL and am struggling with triggers. Say I have a table called members with the following data

```
MemberID(PK) (INT) | Name (VARCHAR)|
1                  | Barry         |
```

and another table called class with the following data

```
ClassID(PK) (INT) | ClassType(VARCHAR) | ClassSize(INT)
1                 | Boxing             | 20
```

I also have a link entity table called members_has_class with the following data

```
Members_MemberID(FK) (INT) | Class_ClassID (FK) (INT)|
1                          | 1                       |
```

I'd like to make a trigger that checks the class is not full when a user likes to sign up to a class where the information entered (Member ID and Class ID) is inserted into members_has_class table.

So for example, if boxing has  a class size of 20, the trigger checks that there are not already 20 people signed up to it. So if there are not 20 people already in the members_has_class they can sign up, if the class is full it does not allow sign up. I was thinking I would have to count how many of the same class id values there are and compare if it is bigger and smaller than the class size.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest avoiding `TRIGGERs`.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT COUNT(*) ... FOR UPDATE;
if there is still room
    INSERT ... to add student to class
else
    give error
COMMIT;
```

That is, write application code perform the logic.  (TRIGGERs and FOREIGN KEYs have limited capabilities.)

Put it into a transaction to prevent another student from sneaking in while you are checking availability.  Note also the `FOR UPDATE`.

The above transaction could be put in a `STORED PROCEDURE`, but I suggest you do it in application code, rather than also taking on the potential challenges of SPs.

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory, but MySQL doesn't allow the trigger to query the same table. In other words you should create a trigger for table `members_has_class`, and the trigger should run a `SELECT` on `members_has_class`, but this is not possible, you would get an error.

An alternative is to add a column to `class` table, which contains the number of students. The initial value should be 0, then you could update that value with a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` on the table `members_has_class`. There should also be a trigger `BEFORE DELETE` and - even if apparently it doesn't make sense - it's better to have a trigger `BEFORE UPDATE`, which checks if you are changing the class of a member.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still struggling to implement your solution